# Lefschetz type theorems/conjectures for algebraic $K$-theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory, motivic-cohomology

Lefschetz hyperplane theorem, compares the homology/cohomology of a projective variety with a hyperplane section of it and claims they are isomorphic in certain ranges. There are Lefschetz type theorems for picard groups. There is also a such a conjectures for Chow groups. I was wondering whether there are similar theorem/conjectures for algebraic $K$-theory or motivic cohomology with different coefficients?

Comment: presumably you already know about infinitesimal lefschetz for k-cohomology?

Comment: I've seen a version of that, deals with Chow groups.

Comment: yeah it's the only way I (obviously this is a defect on my part) can imagine such a statement holding. The problem is that K-theory is very "noncommutative" but the lefschetz hyperplane theorem is very "commutative"; in particular it is a statement which needs "degree" or "dimension" to formulate.